# Refer back to subset dataframe when using stat_function or geom_function

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am trying to plot out curves using a dataframe that includes only the model coefficients. I would like one curve for each rep within a group, but I can't figure out how to make `stat_function` find the respective coefficients. Here's a reprex with the (unsuccessful) method I have tried.

```
df <- data.frame(cohort = c("la", "la", "la", "li", "li", "li", "lo", "lo", "lo"), 
             rep = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), 
             coef_a = c(0.000000308, -0.000000179, -0.000000219, -0.000000195,
                        -0.000000179, -0.000000219, -0.000000195,-0.000000308, -0.000000179),
             coef_b = c(-0.0168, 0.0112, 0.0126, 0.0119, 0.0112, 0.0126, 0.0119, -0.0168, 
                         0.0112), 
             coef_c = c(437, 9.90, 1.56, 44.5, 9.90, 1.56, 44.5,437, 9.90)) 


curve <- function(x, a, b, c){a * x^2 + b * x + c}


df %>%
  filter(cohort == "la") %>%
  ggplot(aes(color = rep)) +
  xlim(20000, 50000) +
  stat_function(fun = curve, args = list(a = .a, b = .b, c = .c))
```

In my real data, I also have a `facet_grid` at the end of this because there are two more groupings. Hopefully if we figure this out, all will come through to the facets?

Answer (score 0):

First of all. `ggplot2` uses a `+` instead of a pipe `%>%`.

One approach to achieve your desired result would be to loop over the rows of your data frame using e.g. `purrr::pmap` to make a list of the `stat_function` layers which can then be added to your ggplot like so:

```r
df <- data.frame(cohort = c("la", "la", "la", "li", "li", "li", "lo", "lo", "lo"), 
                 rep = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), 
                 coef_a = c(0.000000308, -0.000000179, -0.000000219, -0.000000195,
                            -0.000000179, -0.000000219, -0.000000195,-0.000000308, -0.000000179),
                 coef_b = c(-0.0168, 0.0112, 0.0126, 0.0119, 0.0112, 0.0126, 0.0119, -0.0168, 
                            0.0112), 
                 coef_c = c(437, 9.90, 1.56, 44.5, 9.90, 1.56, 44.5,437, 9.90)) 


curve <- function(x, a, b, c){a * x^2 + b * x + c}

library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

layer_fun <- df %>%
  filter(cohort == "la") %>%
  pmap(function(...) {
  args <- list(...)
  stat_function(fun = curve, args = list(a = args$coef_a, b = args$coef_b, c = args$coef_c))
})

  ggplot(df, aes(color = rep)) +
  xlim(20000, 50000) +
  layer_fun
```

[image: curves from la group]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: The filter and aesthetics didn't come through here, but I made a few edits to make the filter work. Thanks!